# RN-52 - Bluetooth Audio Module two way communication with Android

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, android

Im planning a project that involves sending data from a door phone to an android phone and vice versa using the [RN-52](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11678) chip from sparkfun. Because of the nature of the project it is necessary to be able to send and receive audio simultaneously, is this possible? I've done some googling and it seems to me impossible because of sink/source, since you cant have both at the same time (using A2DP).

Can this be done with another profile I don't know of?

Even if that were to work, can the chip handle two way communication?

Is this project feasible with BT, or should I be looking at WIFI-communication instead? 
Ultimately it would be nice to be able to use BT because of costs.

Edit: Can I use bluetooth hands free profile? This profile is (AFAIK) intended to send audio to and from a phone (amongst other functionality). The chip does support HFP/HSP, can this work?

Comment: Regardless of channel issues, full duplex audio is likely to cause feedback issues which are tricky to eliminate.

Comment: Well, I guess I could make it half-duplex though. I.e you hold a button on the phone to talk, and is not able to press it when someone is talking in the other end.